# comparing recent averaged values to a current value in R

Tags: r

I am using Rstudio (version .99.903), have a PC (windows 8). I have a follow up question from yesterday as the problem became more complicated. Here is what the data looks like:

```
 Number     Trial       ID  Open date   Enrollment rate
 420        NCT00091442 9   1/28/2005   0.2
 1476       NCT00301457 26  2/22/2008   1
 10559      NCT01307397 34  7/28/2011   0.6
 6794       NCT00948675 53  5/12/2010   0
 6451       NCT00917384 53  8/17/2010   0.3
 8754       NCT01168973 53  1/19/2011   0.2
 8578       NCT01140347 53  12/30/2011  2.4
 11655      NCT01358877 53  4/2/2012    0.3
 428        NCT00091442 55  9/7/2005    0.1
 112        NCT00065325 62  10/15/2003  0.2
 477        NCT00091442 62  11/11/2005  0.1
 16277      NCT01843374 62  12/16/2013  0.2
 17386      NCT01905657 62  1/8/2014    0.6
 411        NCT00091442 66  1/12/2005   0
```

What I need to do is compare the enrollment rate of the most current date within a given ID to the average of those values that are up to one year prior to it. For instance, for ID 53, the date of 1/19/2011 has an enrollment rate of 0.2 and I would want to compare this against the average of 8/17/2010 and 5/12/2010 enrollment rates (e.g., 0.15).

If there are no other dates within the ID prior to the current one, then the comparison should not be made. For instance, for ID 26, there would be no comparison. Similarly, for ID 53, there would be no comparison for 5/12/2010.

When I say "compare" I am not doing any analysis or visualization. I simply want a new column that takes the average value of those enrollment rates up to one year prior to the current one (I will be plotting them and percentile ranking them later). There are >20,000 data points. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Verbose but possibly high performance way of doing this. No giant for loops looping over all the rows of the data frame. The two sapply loops only operate on a big numeric vector, which should be relatively quick regardless of your data row count. But I'm sure someone will waltz in with a trivial dplyr solution soon enough.

Approach assumes that your data is first sorted by `ID` then by `Opendata`. If they are not sorted, you need to sort them first.

```
# Find indices where the same ID is above and below it
A = which(unlist(sapply(X = rle(df$ID)$lengths,
FUN = function(x) {if(x == 1) return(F)
                   if(x == 2) return(c(F,F))
                   if(x >= 3) return(c(F,rep(T, x-2),F))})))

# Store list of date, should speed up code a tiny bit
V_opendate = df$Opendate
# Further filter on A, where the date difference < 365 days
B = A[sapply(A, function(x) (abs(V_opendate[x]-V_opendate[x-1]) < 365) & (abs(V_opendate[x]-V_opendate[x+1]) < 365))]

# Return actual indices of rows - 1, rows +1
C = sapply(B, function(x) c(x-1, x+1), simplify = F)

# Actually take the mean of these cases
D = sapply(C, function(x) mean(df[x,]$Enrollment))

# Create new column rate and fill in with value of C. You can do the comparison from here.
df[B,"Rate"] = D

   Number       Trial ID   Opendate Enrollmentrate Rate
1     420 NCT00091442  9 2005-01-28            0.2   NA
2    1476 NCT00301457 26 2008-02-22            1.0   NA
3   10559 NCT01307397 34 2011-07-28            0.6   NA
4    6794 NCT00948675 53 2010-05-12            0.0   NA
5    6451 NCT00917384 53 2010-08-17            0.3 0.10
6    8754 NCT01168973 53 2011-01-19            0.2 1.35
7    8578 NCT01140347 53 2011-12-30            2.4 0.25
8   11655 NCT01358877 53 2012-04-02            0.3   NA
9     428 NCT00091442 55 2005-09-07            0.1   NA
10    112 NCT00065325 62 2003-10-15            0.2   NA
11    477 NCT00091442 62 2005-11-11            0.1   NA
12  16277 NCT01843374 62 2013-12-16            0.2   NA
13  17386 NCT01905657 62 2014-01-08            0.6   NA
14    411 NCT00091442 66 2005-01-12            0.0   NA
14    411 NCT00091442 66  1/12/2005           0.00    NA
```

The relevant rows are calculated. You can do your comparison with the newly created `Rate` column.

You might have to change the code a little since I changed removed the space in the column names

```
df = read.table(text = " Number     Trial       ID  Opendate   Enrollmentrate
 420        NCT00091442 9   1/28/2005   0.2
                1476       NCT00301457 26  2/22/2008   1
                10559      NCT01307397 34  7/28/2011   0.6
                6794       NCT00948675 53  5/12/2010   0
                6451       NCT00917384 53  8/17/2010   0.3
                8754       NCT01168973 53  1/19/2011   0.2
                8578       NCT01140347 53  12/30/2011  2.4
                11655      NCT01358877 53  4/2/2012    0.3
                428        NCT00091442 55  9/7/2005    0.1
                112        NCT00065325 62  10/15/2003  0.2
                477        NCT00091442 62  11/11/2005  0.1
                16277      NCT01843374 62  12/16/2013  0.2
                17386      NCT01905657 62  1/8/2014    0.6
                411        NCT00091442 66  1/12/2005   0", header = T)
```